# Regex which captures url prefix but excludes www

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I've been trying to wrap my mind around regex usage in javascript (not an expert) but I've been unable to solve this issue.

**This is a pattern for my url:**

```
https://www.prefix.site.com
```

**And my current regex:**

```
/(?:(\w+)\.)?site\.com
```

What I need to do is capture the prefix that's before '.site', but I don't want to include the 'https://www.', given that both 'www.' and my prefix may or may not be present. An example of my prefix could be an environment, e.g. https://testing.site.com

The issue with the regex from above is that IF there is a 'www.' without my prefix, then it will capture the 'www.' as prefix and that's not what I need.

I kinda solved it with negative lookbehind, but since it's not available in javascript, I cannot use it.

Any tips would be really appreciated!

Comment: Here's a good resource: https://regex101.com/

Comment: /.*(?:(\w+)\.)?site\.com/U This should work

Comment: Oh sorry, U modifier is not available in Javascript. This should work though /.*?(?:(\w+)\.)?site\.com/ There is a lot to improve generally in this regex though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very beginning of the capturing group, you can negative lookahead for `www.` to ensure that the capturing group will only match if it contains something other than `www.`:

```
((?!www\.)\b\w+\.)?site\.com
```

https://regex101.com/r/K8btgd/1

Note the word boundary `\b` - that's to make sure that the capturing group either starts after a non-word character (like a `/` or a `.`), or won't match at all (to prevent matches such as `ww.site.com` where a third `w` precedes it)

Comment: This looks neat and clean, although it seems to be capturing the dot (.) that follows the prefix.
I didn't know about the \b syntax tho!

Comment: Ah right, for the dot, just move it out into an optional non-capturing group, similar to what you were doing originally https://regex101.com/r/K8btgd/2

Comment: @dellwarrior When an answer solves your problem, consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the following would work for you:

```
https?://(?:w{3}\.)?(\w+)\.site\.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Per your needs, this expression will only capture the prefix: `(?!w{1,3}\.)[\w-]+(?=\.example)`

https://regex101.com/r/X4L9ZZ/2

It supports dashes as well as properly allowing "w"s in your prefix/sub-domain.

Sample:

```
const getPrefix = uri => {
  const matched = uri.match(/(?!w{1,3}\.)[\w-]+(?=\.example)/);
  return matched && matched[0];
}

getPrefix("https://www.prefix.example.com"); // "prefix"
getPrefix("https://prefix.example.com"); // "prefix"
getPrefix("https://www.example.com"); // null
getPrefix("https://example.com"); // null
```

Good news is that "lookbehinds" will soon be fully supported in JS. It's already at stage 4 and just needs to be implemented across browsers! https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind